# Increase width of x axis in forest plot

Tags: python, x-axis, forest-plots

A forest plot has the adequate graph width, but within this, my x axis is compressed to one side. How can I get it to fill the space designated for the graph?

```
forestplot(Tab1[,1:8],
           mean=Tab1numbers[,1],
           lower=Tab1numbers[,2],
           upper=Tab1numbers[,3],
           graphwidth=unit(7,"cm"),
           colgap=unit(2,"mm"),
           align=c("l","c","c","c","c","c","c"),
           graph.pos=6,
           new_page = F,
           boxsize = .25, 
           line.margin =0.5,
           is.summary=c(T,T,rep(FALSE,17)),
           clip=c(0.5,25), 
           xlab="Odds Ratio",
           xticks=c(0.8,1,2,3,6,10,30),
           zero=1,
           xlog=T,
           title="Reasons for attendance",
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = gpar(fontfamily = "sans",fontsize=9),
                        xlab= gpar(fontfamily = "sans",fontsize=10),
                        ticks= gpar(fontfamily = "sans",fontsize=11),
                        legend = gpar(fontfamily = "sans",fontsize=10)),
           col=fpColors(box=c("dark red"),
                    line=c("dark red"),
                    summary=c("dark red")))
```

[image]